# Upgrading OpenSSH when OS version is outdated

Tags: rhel, upgrade, openssh

I would like to upgrade OpenSSH version (currently version is OpenSSH_4.3p2, using protocol OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5). However, it seems I cannot upgrade it because OS Linux itself has a very old version (RH5.9).

I was initially trying to communicate with a remote SFTP server using various protocols (aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc).

But for all, the feedback was the same below :

```
$ sftp -o IdentityFile=/.ssh/al-texolanv-prod-2023-03-01-private_key -o Cipher=aes256-cbc 'al-texolanv-prod@10.152.50.112'
Connecting to 10.152.50.112... no matching mac found:
client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
server umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
$
```

I have since been told that upgrading openSSH was required but I have also been told how complicated it would be due to the OS' version

Do you know how I could proceed ? Let me know if my request was not clear enough or if you need more input.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could build a new OpenSSL/openssh/whatever needed in `/usr/local` and stop/disable your system daemon and start using the one in `/usr/local`.  I absolutely hate this approach because a ton of other things on your server could be insecure, even as core ones as glibc/pam.d/etc. If you still need this server the best thing to do going forward is to virtualize it and move it into a DMZ and firewall it properly. I'm pretty sure it runs on very outdated feeble HW, so virtualizing it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Assiming that there is a **REALLY** good reason why you cannot upgrade the entire OS, you'll either need to build a parallel software stack from tarball (you'll probably need to compile more than just openssh) or use a separate host as a proxy. Do make sure its only accepting insecure connections from this RHEL5.9 box.